# Apache doesn't execute PHP files, but makes me download them

Tags: apache2

So I setup my server using [this](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_debian_lamp_server) tutorial, and when the test.php file works with no problem when I enter the address using my server's IP as

```
http://1.2.3.4/test.php
```

However, if I use virtualhosts, the browser just offers to download the file rather than executing it. So this:

```
http://blog.mydomain.com/test.php
```

offers to download the file rather than executing the script.

The code I use in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf for virtual hosts is the following:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
Include /etc/apache2/mods-available/php5.conf

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/folder1
    ServerName www.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /path/to/vhosts/folder2
    ServerName blog.mydomain.com
</VirtualHost>

NameVirtualHost *:80
```

Though I have to say that when I restart the apache2 server I get a warning message:

```
[....] Restarting web server: apache2
[Sun Jan 19 13:33:40 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts ... waiting [Sun Jan 19 13:33:41 2014] [warn] NameVirtualHost *:80 has no VirtualHosts
```

Comment: Are you aware that that is a LAMP server?

Comment: @Braiam to be honest I'm lost between LAMP and Apache... I don't know the difference... however, you got an answer to my question?

Comment: where do i find this directory?
it does not work for me. please help?
how do i reload vhost vie terminal?

Comment: @Godworld What directory? Apache config files are in `/etc/apache2/`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP script not executing on Apache server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305680/apache-virtual-host-not-parsing-php). It turns out I had to enable some modules...

---

Taken from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9313316/2734389) by [user1075581](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075581/user1075581):

> This finally put me on the right path:
>
> http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/php-not-working-on-one-vhost-but-works-on-all-others-851093/
>
> Here's the solution:
>
> In the `<Directory>` section, I included these lines:
>
> ```php
> <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
>     php_admin_flag engine on
> </IfModule>
> <IfModule mod_php5.c>
>     php_admin_flag engine on
> </IfModule>
> ```
>
> Or, a redacted copy/paste of the solution on my server:
>
> ```php
> <Directory "/var/www/vhosts/A2/httpdocs">
>     <IfModule sapi_apache2.c>
>         php_admin_flag engine on
>     </IfModule>
>     <IfModule mod_php5.c>
>         php_admin_flag engine on
>     </IfModule>
>
>     (Other configuration parameters)
>
> </Directory>
> ```

Answer (score 20):

I got it to work with the line:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php7.0

sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for naming this library. I knew I had to install a library to fix this but did not know the name.

Comment: The `libapache2-mod-php7.0` package does not exist in the main Ubuntu repository. Not until 16.04 is released. You should use `libapache2-mod-php5` instead.

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes even worse things can happen....
I just forgot to install php

Comment: I hardly think this can be called a real answer, but I guess it sorta is.

Comment: When you have a reasonable number of machines and it's reasonably late in the evening, this is definitely a valid answer.

Comment: A valid answer indeed. I had a problem juggling php5, php5-cli, php5-fpm, and php-whatnot. Apache was just missing the _right_ package.

Answer (score 0):

I've been searching this for a long time and I just found a solution that works in my case.  I had put my file (`processorder.php5`) in the directory `/var/www` in a standard ubuntu installation.  I thought this was the place that php looked.  But for html (or php files which are probably considered the same thing) it looked in `/var/www/html`, ie the `html` subdirectory of `/var/www`.

When I moved my file down a directory it worked.  I'm suspicious because I don't think I've seen this documented anywhere

Answer (score 0):

permission problems can also lead to get this strange behavior

```
chmod -R u=rwX,go=rX my_publishing_directory
```

will get rid of permission problems (644 on files and 755 on directories)