# Php doesn't work on Apache server

Tags: apache2, php

I installed LAMP

```
sudo tasksel install lamp-server
```

I can run my site, but the php code is just [displayed as text](http://i33.fastpic.ru/big/2014/0414/f8/0e1c35e4f4a75fcc496b122445d8eef8.png).

I have tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/407744/apache-doesnt-execute-php-files-but-makes-me-download-them) solution, but it didn't help me.

When I try to run php script with terminal:

```
user@pc:~/ooo$ php index.htm
```

I get just php code.

When

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status
php -v
```

I get

```
 * apache2 is running
PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4 (cli) (built: Apr  9 2014 17:11:57) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.5.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.3, Copyright (c) 1999-2014, by Zend Technologies
```

How to solve this?

Comment: It should be `sudo apt-get install lamp-server^`. Maybe there are packages you left out..

Comment: Sorry if this insults your intelligence: Is your code wrapped in php tags `<?php ...code... ?>`

Comment: @dan08 sigh! how did I miss that. That's not an insult. That's another confirmation to proceed further by assisting.. :)

Comment: yeah, these tags are there.

Comment: Can you visit this [**link**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) and copy the php script shown in the first example, save it `test.php` or whatever you like with the `.php` extension, then open that file and let us know whether the output **Hello World** can be seen??

Comment: Hello World is work

Comment: Its must be something about your file, it is not getting passed to the php interpreter. The most common causes are missing tags and incorrect extensions.

Comment: I hope you're familiar with `php` scripting and how it works. By the look of your comment and the picture you've posted. Its not the `php` which is troubling, its your script.

Comment: But why this file good working on other server in Internet? Yeah, I know php is not so bad.

Comment: Try to install xampp it might work i am pasting a link here which explains about its installation and running php script on it too. Hope this might help you......just give it a try..... 1) To install XAMPP http://www.codingdevil.com/2014/02/how-to-install-xampp-on-ubuntulinux.html 2)To run PHP script http://www.codingdevil.com/2014/02/how-to-run-xampp-on-ubuntu.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that your script is not getting passed to the php interpreter, and is simply outputting the text of the file. This is a common error and is almost always due:

1. Using a file ending other than php (e.x. htm or html)
2. Not using php tag `<?php ... ?>` or as Nathan mentioned using improper tags.

You may see other servers that use file extensions other than `.php` or use shorthand tags.

Both of these can be configured to be permitted:

[Allowing php short tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185320/how-to-enable-php-short-tags)

[Allowing additional file extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155256/how-to-save-php-file-as-php-or-html-extension)

Short tags used to be allowed by default, but have fallen out of favour.
Its best to use the full tags `<?php ?>` if your starting something new or just learning php.

Answer (score 4):

By looking at your last updated edit, I see the file is not saved as `index.php`. You see, `php` scripts will not work when you save it on an `.htm` or `.html` extension. In order for the `php` file to take effect, you will need rename `index.htm` to `index.php`.

## EDIT

As per my last comment with a testing php script link, it seems there's no problem with your `php` pack or the **lamp-server**. It is something to do with your `php` script itself. Better have a look into the script properly and fix it have a proper outcome.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I renamed file in index.php and got same result.

Comment: what happens when you navigate to `http://localhost` using one of your web browser?? Could you please edit your question and update the output for `sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 status` and `php -v`

Comment: I think my server does not see the file .htaccess. Because if I delete it on the production server - the result is the same. Why did he ignore .htaccess?

Comment: A directive in your Virtual host file. Add/Change the line `AllowOverride All`

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the code is using short tags `<? ?>` instead of the normal `<?php ?>`. You need to enable short tags in php.ini.

Find this in php.ini: `short_open_tag`

Set it to 1 and restart Apache.

Comment: Or better yet, use the normal tags.

Comment: True enough, but for something like a web application this can be a daunting task :)

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. You need to check which are your PHP version first.

```
php -v
```

After install `libapache2-mod-phpX`

X= your php version number. It will ask for a few dependencies, say yes for all.