# Apache unable to connect to MySQL

Tags: apache2, mysql

I installed apache server ([this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447750/php-doesnt-work-on-apache-server) story). I cannot connect with remote (I tried local too) mysql server. After a long loading page I get error **MySQL database connect failure**. Mysql server is far from me. On same page which locate in Internet with same settings is good work. How to solve this?

When I typed in terminal:

```
mysql -u username -h x.xx.xx.x -p
```

After a minute I get:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxxxxxx' (110)
```

I cannot visit **localhost/phpadmin/**, because I get 403 error. I doubt the correctness of the phpadmin settings...

Comment: what is the URL are you trying to access to your server. you'll need `phpmyadmin` to access the database. If I'm not mistakn, lamp has it all with pack. Try, `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`

Answer (score 0):

How are you connecting to the database, if it is with php try

```
mysql_connect("localhost", username, password);
```

with localhost as your host.

Answer (score 0):

Open up your terminal or console and type the following:

```
mysql -u username -h x.xx.xx.x -p
```

then enter your password

This gives you the assurance that the connection from your host it works, and if not, return a useful error output.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should allow IP or port 3306 on firewal and grant permission for user@IP for local visit with command:

```
sudo ufw allow from IP/subnet to any port 22
```

- Grant permission user connect from remote on Mysql:

  ```
  GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO root@'IP' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' with grant option;
  ```

  flush privileges;