# PHP script not executing on Apache server

Tags: apache2, php

I have just reinstalled Apache and PHP5 but when I visit my doc root it just downloads a "download" file. And when I try *documentroot*/index.php it just downloads the PHP file.

I have PHP installed but Apache doesn't seem to want to execute it.
People suggested adding a 'Load Module' line to my `httpd.conf` but I don't have that file.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Typing:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

will install everything you need and will start the apache server with support for PHP.

To verify that the php module is loaded, type:

```
a2query -m php5
```

if not enabled, then load with:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

### **Update for php7.x (tested on Ubuntu 16.04, 16.10, 18.04, 18.10**)

Thanks to the comments, I update the answer for php7.x.

Install:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php7.x libapache2-mod-php7.x
```

Verify:

```
a2query -m php7.x
```

Load:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.x
```

Restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: It would be better to use `a2enmod` than to copy the file manually between mods-available and mods-enabled.  `a2enmod` creates a symlink and so you'll only have one copy of the configuration.

Comment: @jkt123 you're right. thanks for the advice, i edit my answer.

Comment: In my case, it says "ERROR:module php5 does not exist!" it is installed

Comment: for ubuntu 16.04 with php7
I have executed these commands in order
`apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`,
`a2query -m php7.0`,
`service apache2 restart`

Comment: For ubuntu 14.04 : # a2query -m php7.0
php7.0 (enabled by site administrator)
Still php code is not executing

Comment: When opened in browser : // Show warning if a PHP version below 5.4.0 is used, this has to happen here
// because base.php will already use 5.4 syntax.

Comment: Thanks for the Ubuntu 16 update. I had forgotten to install `libapache2-mod-php7.0`, so output of `a2query -m php7.0` was empty...

Comment: There is another version of the install command which uses the default version for one’s Ubuntu version, see https://askubuntu.com/a/837733/250300.

Comment: Fixed on debian after a couple of days trying different distro, I had to install `libapache2-mod-php` & `php` then enable `sudo a2enmod php7.3`.

Comment: Thanks it's working

Answer (score 21):

Another common cause is that php short tags `<?` are not enabled by the default php.ini configuration, so after an upgrade or reinstall, that setting may be turned off and php code may depend on it. Try replacing `<?` with `<?php`.

([Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9305680/apache-virtual-host-not-parsing-php))

Answer (score 18):

**Ubuntu 16.04** has moved to PHP 7. This single command will do the job for you:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php
```

Here `libapache2-mod-php` is a meta-package that installs libapache2-mod-php7.

Answer (score 7):

I ran into the same problem, but my particular problem was unique. I was running in a user directory (using mod_userdir) - meaning you access my webpage with http://host.name.com/~username/example.php

This is disabled by default in php*.conf in my mods-enabled directory. I had to modify it to comment it out:

```
#<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
#    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
#        php_admin_flag engine Off
#    </Directory>
#</IfModule>
```

That was a pain to figure out..

Well, I doubt anybody had THIS particular problem, but I figured I'd add it because it was perplexing as crud to me and MAYBE somebody is doing the same thing. Nobody uses ~/user anymore I guess, except me.

You have to restart apache after this of course.

Comment: Not so unique after all :p

Comment: Awesome find, thank you!

Answer (score 6):

For people who have found this post from Google almost 6 years in the future (and beyond!), you may run into this problem with Apache 2 and PHP 7 while also using the `UserDir` module.

Another possible cause of this problem could be that you are trying to run the script in a "user directory" from the the `UserDir` module.  Running PHP scripts in user directories is disabled by default.  You will run into this problem if the script is in the `public_html` directory in your home folder and you are trying to access it from `http://localhost/~your_username`.

To fix this, open up `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php7.2.conf`.  You must comment or delete the tag block at the bottom that reads

```xml
<IfModule mod_userdir.c>
    <Directory /home/*/public_html>
        php_admin_flag engine Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

Open `php.ini` with `nano` in terminal:

```
sudo nano /etc/php/php5.6/apache2/php.ini
```

Then change:

```
short_open_tag = Off
```

to

```
short_open_tag = On
```

Then save and then restart apache2:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Or fix the PHP scripts :-) `This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It is generally recommended that <?php and ?> should be used and that this feature should be disabled [...]`

Answer (score 1):

My case was a little different. I upgraded from Ubuntu 19.04 to 19.10. While upgration it installed php 7.3 (where as php 7.2 was already installed). With 2 versions installed **a2query -m php7.3** return **No module matches php7.3**.

Solution I found was from [how-to-install-php-7-3-on-ubuntu](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-php-7-3-on-ubuntu-16-04/).

To set PHP 7.0 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.0
```

To set PHP 7.2 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

To set PHP 7.3 as the default, run

```
update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.3
```

Before we can configure Apache to use PHP 7.3, we need to disable the old version of PHP 7.0 by typing

```
a2dismod php7.2
```

Now enable the newly installed PHP 7.3 version with the following command:

```
a2enmod php7.3
```

Restart the Apache web server for the changes to take effect:

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Thx my friend, it works perfectly for me. I upgrade my system from 18.04 to 19.10 and php stoped to work. Your tips worked to new version 7.3.