# Displaying code as text php

Tags: webserver

I have this code on my website:

```
<textarea name="code" cols="20" rows="5">
<?php
echo "Your IP is: ". $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]; 
?>
</textarea>
```

I want it so that it shows the code as text, not run it.

Can this be done?

Comment: This isn't question for askubuntu.com, try on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) or [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [php not executing on apache server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-not-executing-on-apache-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either wrap your code in `<xmp>` tags:

```
<xmp>html code</xmp>
```

Or use PHP's built in htmlentities function:

```
$hmtlcode='stuff';
echo htmlentities($htmlcode);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could remove the `<?php` starting and `?>` ending tag