# php showing source code in localhost

Tags: apache2, lamp, localhost

i have apache2 (Server version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server built:   Mar 10 2015 13:05:59), mysql and phpmyadmin.

While accessing php file by http://localhost/ or http://ipaddress

It shows up source code instead of executing.

Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP script not executing on Apache server](http://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server)

Comment: @muru that question is different from this. This displays the source code while that question specifies that file is downloaded instead of executing.

Comment: that just depends on the media type set for the file, the core problem is the same.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can think of 3 possibilities:

1. You don't have PHP installed. In that case run:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install php php-mysql
   ```
2. You have PHP installed but not enabled. You can try running:

   ```
   sudo a2enmod php7  
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```
3. You have PHP installed and enabled but you haven't restarted apache.

   ```
   sudo service apache2 restart
   ```

Comment: none of them worked for me. Here are the results: **1** . `E: Unable to locate pachage php` I tried with php5 which gives `php5 is already the newest version.` **2** . `ERROR: Module php5 does not exist!`. I tried with php which gives same error. **3** `The apache2 configtest failed.`

Comment: It seems you don't have modphp installed... Try the following sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 and then restart apache... if it still doesn't work try running sudo a2enmod php5 again.

Comment: I didn't helped me. Now I am left with one solution and that is to reinstall Ubuntu. But, if php starts working prior to this, it will be life saver to me.

Comment: In tat case you might want to completely reinstall apache, php & mysql. In terminal do the following: `sudo apt-get purge apache2 php5 mysql-server` This will completely remove the packages including their configuration files so if you have made any important changes better make a backup of /etc/apache2 , /etc/mysql and /etc/php5 first. After that do the following: `sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 mysql-server` . Note that it is important to install them all at once because otherwise modphp doesn't always get installed.

Comment: You are missing the package which installs the PHP5 module used by Apache. The package is called `libapache2-mod-php5`.

Answer (score 9):

you need to install libapache2-mod-php

`sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php`

it is no longer pulled by other packages as a dependency
in 14.04 it named libapache2-mod-php5, in 16.04 they dropped the number at the end for a meta package

Answer (score 5):

For Ubuntu 20.04, I had to run:

```
sudo a2dismod mpm_event
```

It tells you to restart Apache2, but you don't need to at this point.  Then enable php 7.4 using:

```
sudo a2enmod php7.4
```

Then restart Apache2: `sudo systemctl restart apache2`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks finally I found your answer to make it work

Comment: Worked like a charm on fresh install with ubuntu 20.04. Thanks a lot !

Comment: @FlyGuy - What if server is using map_event mode?

Answer (score 3):

After Upgrading to Ubuntu 17.10 this morning my answer was a combination of Sledge Hammer's and GM-Script-Writer-62850's answer. The exact commands I needed were:

```
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php
sudo a2enmod php7.1
systemctl restart apache2
```

Answer (score 2):

After upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04, I also faced this problem and after reinstall phpmyadmin not working but i searched for 1-2 hours and finally this work for me. I have php 8.1 and mysql 8.0

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php8.1
sudo a2enmod php8.1
systemctl restart apache2
```

Comment: Worked like charm!