# Php not working?

Tags: apache2, php, xampp

I got this demo http://www.coolphptools.com/color_extract#demo working in xampp on Windows. But now I want to use it on apache2 in Ubuntu. I installed apache2 and php 7 and put the files into `/var/www/html/` But I think php is not working. It only shows the html part but nothing from the php code... Do I need to install something else?

I also ran

```
a2enmod proxy_fcgi setenvif
a2enconf php7.0-fpm
service apache2 reload
```

after installing php 7 but it doesn't work.

I thought it might be a problem with the php, because no php from the demo was working.
But when I add a simple php script to get the current time, that is working fine. So now I am even more confused what is causing this issue... Maybe it is a problem with the code? But why did it work fine on xampp?

I also double checked the answer on this [PHP script not executing on Apache server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server) post. And everything seems to be correct

Answer (score 0):

Type

```
sudo apt-get install apache2 php5 libapache2-mod-php5
```

will install everything you need and will start the apache server with support for PHP.

To verify that the php module is loaded, type:

```
a2query -m php5
```

if not enabled, then load with:

```
sudo a2enmod php5
```

and restart apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment but I tried that already :) I found the problem was an image library for php called php-gd

Comment: can you please share the problem in details

Comment: I had to run sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd to implement the gd library which was required for the demo. I didnt notice that because I did not need it on xampp.

Comment: follow the link it may help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-upgrade-to-php-7-on-ubuntu-14-04

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I didn't notice,

Requirements:

```
PHP 4.0.2 or higher
GD2 image library
```

On the website of the demo. I had to run:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-gd
```

to implement the gd library.