# phpmyadmin homepage display problem

Tags: server, apache2, php, phpmyadmin

I just reformat my computer back to Ubuntu (16.04) and installed LAMP by using codes:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install apache2
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo apt-get install php
```

Then I installed phpMyAdmin by using the steps below:
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04/

and I changed one of the commands on step 3 to

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

(because i don't know what is vim...)

then after all that I open phpMyAdmin (from `http://localhost/phpmyadmin`) 
and it looks like this:

[image: what's my phpMyAdmin looks like...]

Comment: Your problem is that PHP is not being executed. Please check the following answer: http://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server/451740#451740

Comment: Off topic: You do not need `Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`. phpMyAdmin is included through `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` so you can switch it on/off by `a2enconf` / `a2disconf`.

Comment: @Dan my php files is working tho...

Comment: @Spas Spasov i dont get what you mean but thanks i found the answer :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dont know how it happens but i used this answer

> Your problem is that PHP is not being executed. Please check the following answer: [PHP script not executing on Apache server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server/451740#451740) – Dan

then still didn't work... (just informing you i did that maybe it contributed something...)

Then i typed to my terminal this `a2enconf` then it works :)  thanks to @Spas Spasov

> Off topic: You do not need Include `/etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf` into `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf.` phpMyAdmin is included through `/etc/apache2/conf-available/phpmyadmin.conf` so you can switch it on/off by `a2enconf` / `a2disconf`. – Spas Spasov