# .php file displayed as source code

Tags: apache2, php

I have installed a default LAMP:

```
ubuntu 16.04
Apache2
MySQL 5.7
PHP 7.0
```

**The default site PHP is working as expected.**

```
000-default.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

However when I add a virtualhost, .php showed as raw code:

```
test.mysite.conf 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/test"

   <Directory "/var/www/test">
       Options Indexes FollowSymlinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Require all granted
       DirectoryIndex index.php
   </Directory>

   <FilesMatch "\.php$">
       Require all granted
       SetHandler proxy:fcgi://127.0.0.1:9000
   </FilesMatch>

   ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/test.my_error.log"
   ServerSignature Off
   CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/test.my_access.log" combined 

   SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Can anyone help anything wrong above or other files might be wrong?

Tks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP script not executing on Apache server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server)

Comment: Not really a dupl of above question. as php is working on the default domain on the same LAMP

Comment: if you remove the FilesMatch for PHP, does anything change?

Comment: Thanks muru - works when i command out the filesmatch - however I m not sure that block doing

Comment: presumably the sethandler you used doesn't match the (default) correct handler.