# Why does my php file not work all of the time?

Tags: apache2, firefox, mysql, php

I have installed `apache2-server`, `php5`, and `mysql-server`. In my browser when I type `localhost` it shows the default apache2 page.

[image]

I also made a `main.php` file in `/var/www/html`. Then when I type `localhost/main.php` it executes and shows the `main.php` file's content in the browser and sometimes it fails. I don't understand what the issue?

I always run `sudo service apache2 restart` but it doesn't solve the issue.

I am using `Ubuntu 14.04` and `firefox 58.0.2`.

Output of -

```
$a2query -m php5
php5 (enabled by maintainer script)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP script not executing on Apache server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server)

Comment: @muru That answer doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: Add the output of `a2query -m php5` to your post, then.

Comment: @muru Sorry, for late. I posted the output.

Comment: What do you mean by "...sometimes it fails." It should always work or always fail. Put something simple in your `main.php`, like `phpinfo ();`.

Comment: @nobody I put a echo statement `echo "This is php";` and I saw the output `This is php` is previous time, but not now. my main.php `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>This is heading</h1>
<?php
echo "This is php";
}
?>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: You should add your apache site configuration... otherwise we are not able to track problem

Comment: @AlvaroNiño I don't know how to do this, if you provide command it is easy to me.

Comment: Well, the PHP you posted, has an error. I think you should delete `}`. Maybe that is why, it does not work. Take a look at error log of you apache server. There should be information about errors in PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

Use `127.0.0.1/main.php` instead of `localhost/main.php`

This works for me.