# Apache2 is not executing php code

Tags: apache2, php

I'm new in linux system. I've problem with executing php code in browser.

- I've installed all packages, by using this command

  `sudo apt install apache2 php libapache2-mod-php`
- Add user to the root group
- When I type `php -V` in command line it works, and `http://localhost` page in browser also works.

But when I try to execute php file it shows as a text instead of executing.

[image: apache2 not executing php code]

So how can I solve this problem ?

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This has been already answered here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/451708/php-script-not-executing-on-apache-server

Comment: @kukulo This answer doesn't help me. I've tried all but not working.

Comment: Try $ php -f somefile.php

Comment: From command line.

Comment: @kukulo it works from command line.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a bash script `start.sh` with following content:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 php -f somefile.php
```

Then start from command line /path/start.sh

Or you can write a `Startphp.desktop` file with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Start php
Comment=Start PHP
Type=Application
Exec=/path/to/php /path/to/somefile.php
Icon=/path/to/your/icon.png
Name[fr_FR]=Start PHP
Categories=
```

Then start with double click on the desktop file in the file manager.

Comment: please mark the answer as a solution for further reference