# How can i watch the PHP preview on browser?

Tags: php, browser

I installed all the LAMP and my file.php is inside /var/www, but when i try to open my file.php on browser for watch the preview the browser ask me a open/download of my file.php.. And the page is blank.
Please help me i tried all kind off solutions online but anything works!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache doesn't execute PHP files, but makes me download them](http://askubuntu.com/questions/407744/apache-doesnt-execute-php-files-but-makes-me-download-them)

Comment: Didn't work....

Answer (score 0):

I am still new, but am working on something similar. My files are in var/www/html. Not sure if moving them to the html folder would help, but might be work a shot. Also, are you accessing from localhost? If you are developing locally, you should be able to type in localhost in your browser and see a file directory, you can also try localhost/(yourfilename).php

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `libapache2-mod-php5` and then you need to enable it by : `a2enmod php5` and finally restart apache and will works.